# three-dimensional graphic objects that are not simple cuboids

Tags: graphics, graphics3d

I am trying to draw some graphics with *Mathematica*. The objects I want to draw are just a little bit more complex than a cuboid -- the difference being that the top and bottom faces are of different depth. Below are two examples of the objects I would like to draw.

```
p01 = RegionPlot3D[ y <= 1 - 0.5 z, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, {z, 0, 1}, 
  Mesh -> None]

p02 = RegionPlot3D[ 
  y <= 0.5 + 0.5 (z - 1), {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, {z, 1, 2}, 
  Mesh -> None]
```

It would be great if I could make these objects using 3-D graphics primitives found in *Mathematica*.  Then I would be able to make 3-D graphics, placing the objects in relation to one another. Below is an example of what I would like to do, basically creating a set of these 6-faced objects and stacking them in relation to one another.

```
cubeA = Cuboid[{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0.5, 1}];

cubeB =  Cuboid[{0, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 2}];

Graphics3D[{cubeA, cubeB}]
```

The example above uses the built-in `Cuboid` object. The objects I would like to make are (only so slightly) more complex than this.  I can create the geometry I am interested in with RegionPlot3D, but I cannot easily combine these. For example, the following fails:

```
Graphics3D[{p01, p02}]
```

I tried to do this with Polygon function, but couldn't quite determine how to extend the examples provided to making a 6-faced objects.

Any recommendations or suggestions would be welcome.
Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried `Show` to combine the `RegionPlots`? What is your desired outcome?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If your polyhedra are as regular* as the two examples, the coordinates can be `Sort`ed into a predictable order, and the following works:

```
hexahedron[faceEqns_] := hexahedron[{x, y, z} /. Solve[faceEqns, {x, y, z}]];
hexahedron[vertices_?MatrixQ] := 
 With[{v = Sort@vertices}, 
  Polygon[v[[#]] & /@ {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {8, 7, 6, 5}, {1, 5, 6, 2},
    {3,  7, 8, 4}, {1, 4, 8, 5}, {2, 6, 7, 3}}]]
```

Just pass the equations for the faces to `hexahedron`:

```
Graphics3D[{
  FaceForm[Red, Yellow], EdgeForm[Directive[Thick, Black]], 
  hexahedron[{y == 0 || y == 1 - 0.5` z, x == 0 || x == 1, z == 0 || z == 1}]
 }]
```

[image: red hexahedron]

Or if you know the vertices, just pass them:

```
Graphics3D[{
  FaceForm[Red, Yellow], EdgeForm[Directive[Thick, Black]], 
  hexahedron[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}, {0.`, 0.5`, 1.`}, {0.`, 1.`, 0.`},
     {1, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 1}, {1.`, 0.5`, 1.`}, {1.`, 1.`, 0.`}}]
  }]
```

---

## Edit: Note* and generalization

**Note***

***...as regular as the two examples:** Note that for the vertices to be sorted into a working order, two conditions have to be met:

1. The `x` coordinates of the region must lie between two quadrilaterals, each in a plane of the form `x == f[y,z]`, such that all the `x` coordinates of the vertices of one quadrilateral are less than the `x` coordinate of each vertex of the other.
2. Similarly one pair of opposite edges of each quadrilateral in 1 must satisfy an additional equation of the form `y == g[z]` such that the `y` coordinates of the end points of one are less than the `y` coordinate each end point of the other.

These restrictions are relaxed in the generalization below.

@belisarius's method with `RegionPlot3D` may be more robust in this regard, although for more skewed shapes `RegionPlot3D` does not always easily find the vertices. Figures can be transformed with `Translate`, `Rotate`, `Scale`, or other `GeometricTransform`s, some examples of which are shown in @belisarius's answer.

**Generalizations**

One can generalize to handle a wider range of equations that describe a simple polyhedron with six quadrilateral faces.

For the kind of `RegionPlot3D` commands in the question, if it predicate and domain arguments can be converted to a certain type of system of inequalities - if they are equivalent to a simple `CylindricalDecomposition` - then the function below will construct the polyhedron.

The function `eqnsFromCmd` tries to contruct a simple cylindrical decomposition,
which `Reduce` will return if one exists.
`Solve` then will yield the vertices, sorted according to which sides they belong.

```
eqnsFromCmd[args_List] := #[[3]] == #[[1]] || #[[3]] == #[[5]] & /@ 
   Quiet[Reduce[And @@ (args /. {{var_Symbol, a_, b_} :> a < var < b, 
         LessEqual -> Less, GreaterEqual -> Greater}), {}], 
    Reduce::ratnz];
sortFn[eqns_] := With[{sides = First /@ List @@ eqns},
    sides /. Thread[{x, y, z} -> #1] & ];
getVertices[eqns_And] := SortBy[{x, y, z} /. Solve[eqns, {x, y, z}], sortFn[eqns]];
```

The new ordering of the vertices requires a new definition of `hexahedron`.  (The `sortFn` basically orders the vertices "binarily", so that the indices of vertices of opposite faces differ by a power of 2.  The use of `GraphicsComplex` is an optional alternative to plugging all the vertices directly into `Polygon` as in the first answer.)

```
hexahedron2[faceEqns_And] := hexahedron2[getVertices[faceEqns]];
Block[{vertices},
 hexahedron2[vertices_?MatrixQ] := 
  Evaluate@GraphicsComplex[vertices, Polygon[{
      {1, 2, 4, 3}, 4 + Reverse@{1, 2, 4, 3},
      {1, 5, 6, 2}, 2 + Reverse@{1, 5, 6, 2},
      {1, 3, 7, 5}, 1 + Reverse@{1, 3, 7, 5}}]]
 ]
```

Example:

```
p03 = RegionPlot3D[ 2 z + y <= 2 x <= 1 + 2 z + 2 y && z/2 <= 2 y <= 1 + z,
   {x, 0, 2.5}, {y, 0, 1}, {z, 0, 1}, Mesh -> None, BoxRatios -> Automatic];

g03 = Graphics3D[{FaceForm[Red, Yellow], EdgeForm[Directive[Thick, Black]], 
  hexahedron2[
   getEqnsFromCmd[{2 z + y <= 2 x <= 1 + 2 z + 2 y && z/2 <= 2 y <= 1 + z,
     {x, 0, 2.5}, {y, 0, 1}, {z, 0, 1}}]]
  }];

Row[{p03, g03}]
```

[image: RegionPlot3D and hexahedron2 output]

*Generating the equations from the command itself*

@belisarius pointed out one can contruct the equations for the figure from an unevaluated `RegionPlot3D` command.  Here are two similar ways.  One way requires `p03` to be defined with `SetDelayed`:

```
Clear[p03];
p03 := RegionPlot3D[ 2 z + y <= 2 x <= 1 + 2 z + 2 y && z/2 <= 2 y <= 1 + z,
  {x, 0, 2.5}, {y, 0, 1}, {z, 0, 1}, Mesh -> None, BoxRatios -> Automatic];
```

In each method we select non-option arguments from the command and pass them to `eqnsFromCmd` above.

```
SetAttributes[eqnsFromCmd, HoldAll];
eqnsFromCmd[plotcmd_Symbol] := eqnsFromCmd[Evaluate@First[Cases[OwnValues@plotcmd, 
      RegionPlot3D[a__] :> Cases[{a}, Except[_Rule]], Infinity]]];
eqnsFromCmd[plotcmd_RegionPlot3D] := eqnsFromCmd[Evaluate@First[Cases[Hold@plotcmd, 
      RegionPlot3D[a__] :> Cases[{a}, Except[_Rule]], Infinity]]];
```

Examples:

```
Graphics3D[{FaceForm[Red, Yellow], EdgeForm[Directive[Thick, Black]], 
  hexahedron2[eqnsFromCmd[p04]]}]

Graphics3D[{FaceForm[Red, Yellow], EdgeForm[Directive[Thick, Black]], 
  hexahedron2[getEqnsFromCmd[
    RegionPlot3D[2 z + y <= 2 x <= 1 + 2 z + 2 y && z/2 <= 2 y <= 1 + z,
     {x, 0, 2.5}, {y, 0, 1}, {z, 0, 1}, Mesh -> None]]]
  }]
```

Output is as above.

*A random example:*

```
eqns1 = And @@ 
   Table[var == Rationalize[RandomReal[.5, 3], 0.001].({x, y, z} /. var -> 0) - 2 ||
         var == Rationalize[RandomReal[.5, 3], 0.001].({x, y, z} /. var -> 0) + 2,
    {var, {x, y, z}}];
Graphics3D[{Hue@RandomReal[], hexahedron2[getVertices[eqns1]]}]
```

[image: Random hexahedron]

Comment: Thanks, very helpful comments.  I can keep this project moving forward now.

Answer (score 3):

```
(*Your plot*)
p01 = RegionPlot3D[y <= 1 - 0.5 z, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, {z, 0, 1}, 
                   Mesh -> None, Axes -> None, Boxed -> False, PlotPoints -> 2, 
                   MaxRecursion -> 0];

(*Isolate the polygons*)
p = Cases[p01, GraphicsComplex[pos_, r___]];
(*Use them in standard graphics contructs*)
Graphics3D[{p, Translate[p, {2, 0, 0}], 
               Translate[Rotate[p, Pi, {0, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 1}], {0, 2, 2}]}, 
           Boxed -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Edit**

Please note that the solution is optimal, in the sense that you are manipulating the minimum possible number of polygons

```
Graphics3D[{Red, PointSize[Large], Cases[p01, GraphicsComplex[pos_, r___] :> Point@pos]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]